# SDl Tridion License

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Can someone share their knowledge about procuring the SDL Tridion licenses in following scenario:

1) Someone wants to take/buy the license for individual purpose - No Organization, No Production websites, No Commercial use - Just for Learning purpose. Is their something called trial license or reciprocal licenses for that sake. Please note the Individual is not an SDL Tridion MVP

2) Someone wants to take/buy the license for Marketing purpose - No Organization, No Commercial Use other than giving demos

3) What is the procedure for an organization to register for being a Partner with SDL Tridion

Comment: I think this is a good question; it comes up enough that I [summarized the ways to get started with Tridion in this post](http://www.createandbreak.net/2011/11/how-to-get-to-play-with-sdl-tridion.html). But software licensing questions may not necessarily be a good fit for StackOverflow. Definitely reach out to SDL, probably on the partner application side. If you suspect being an *individual* is really the problem, apply as an organization, find Tridion work, or consider applying to SDL itself.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming as defined in the help pages.

Comment: Yeah Correct, although it is very useful to the people - The admins can take next action to move it to the sub-StackExchange webste for this purpose - which is www.tridion.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only option I know of (as it seems you have discovered) for a free individual research license is to gain SDL Tridion MVP status, or work for an SDL partner who has a partner licenses. Other than that you may need to purchase one.

You will need to contact SDL about this - They are the only ones who can provide you pricing information on SDL Tridion.

http://www.sdl.com/products/tridion/

Comment: Thanks Chris for your valued comment. I have been involved in procuring SDL Tridion licenses on behalf of an organization multiple times and I know that the license cost depends on a variety of factors like - number of production websites,  number of users, number of CPUs etc. etc. Now all was this when I contacted SDL Tridion on behalf of an organization/partner or a prospective client. The only problem that I am facing is that when I try to contact them as an individual and try to get quotation for my requirement which will absolutely have NO production website, I did not get any reply.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to have an individual license, also not for personal or training use.

When you want to obtain a license for marketing purposes you need to enroll as a partner. You can use the following form to indicate that you want to become one:

http://www.sdl.com/community/partner/partner-programs/tridion-partners/index-tab5.html#10-7785

Often specific POC licenses are issued during sales cycles, but they are specific to the prospect environment.

Comment: You can't make this assumption: "It is not possible to have an individual license, also not for personal or training use". SDL Tridion MVPs have individual licenses, and there are "evaluation purpose licenses" too. As Chris suggests, get in touch with SDL directly.

Comment: Evaluation licenses for free, for individuals starting with Tridion?

Comment: Nuno, thanks for your comments. Just wanted to confirm if this kind of licenses is not available at all even at some cost? I tried contacting SDL Tridion through OOS, got multiple reply about forwarding the request to (& fro) to different department and the first question asked is about the Company Name - When I said I am an individual, I did not received any email reply thereafter. I also tried to call the SDL office in London and did not get any satisfactory reply as soon as I said that I am an individual :(

Comment: @Arjen: Various evaluation licenses are available to SDL Tridion MVPs only (and not to general public)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

SDL now makes a free developer license (not for commercial use) available. Details on their community website here:

https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/w/wiki/863.sdl-web-licenses